# How to pass button into Jquery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, arguments, confirm

I'm using a third party jQuery library called jQquery.confirm. It provides dialogs in jQuery. Upon clicking a button of a particular class I want to use the `confirm()` function in order to bring up the confirmation:

```
$(".btn-danger").click(function(event) {
    //Prevent the button from being clicked.
    event.preventDefault();

    $.confirm({
        text: "Are you sure you want to delete that comment?",
        confirm: function() {
            //Code in here for button to be pressed
        }
    });
});
```

The issue I'm having is with the `confirm: function()`. I'd like to simply simulate clicking the button here. I've tried this but it doesn't seem to recognize the button that I need to click:

```
$(this).trigger("click");
```

I'm guessing I need to pass it as an argument somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the `confirm` handler function the scope of `this` will not refer to the button that was clicked. To fix this you need to store a reference to the clicked button in a variable outside of the `confirm` handler.

Note however that the logic you're creating will end up in a loop; you're clicking the button, showing the `confirm` then clicking the button again programmatically which will just show the `confirm` again and so on ad infinitum. I'd suggest you call a function to do what's needed in the `confirm` action, like this:
Try this:

```
$(".btn-danger").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.confirm({
        text: "Are you sure you want to delete that comment?",
        confirm: function() {
            actionWasConfirmed();
        }
    });
});

var actionWasConfirmed = function() {
    console.log('do something here...');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML Code for your button:

```
<button class="btn-danger" >Delete</button>
```

And 
Javascript function

```
$(".btn-danger").click(function(){
if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete that comment?")){
   //Code in here for button to be pressed
  }
 });
```

Comment: As mentioned - I'm using a 3rd party library for the confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

Every event callback function receives a reference to the event that triggered it. You are already set up to get that reference with your `event` argument. Through that object, you can reference the object that triggered the event (which would the button in your case). So, you could just do this:

```
$(".btn-danger").click(function(event) {

  //Prevent the button from being clicked.
  event.preventDefault();

  $.confirm({
    text: "Are you sure you want to delete that comment?",
    confirm: function() {
        event.target.trigger("click")"
    }
  });
});
```

But, as has been pointed out, a click of the button would cause another click of the button upon confirmation.

Since you just want to delete something upon confirmation, the better approach would be to just delete the entry. In other words, separate your logic. The button click should trigger the confirm and the confirmation should delete the entry, not click the button again.

```
$(".btn-danger").click(function(event) {

  //Prevent the button from being clicked.
  event.preventDefault();

  $.confirm({
    text: "Are you sure you want to delete that comment?",
    confirm: function() {
        // Delete the comment here, don't click more buttons.
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `$(this)` you have to make sure you use it in the correct object. You can't use `$(this)` inside $(confirm) and expect to reference your `$(".btn-danger")`.  Instead it will reference to `$(confirm)` instead of your targeted button.

Take a look at the working example bellow and ask if anything unclear.

```
$(".btn-danger").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Here $(this) references the object you need clicked
    var currentButton = $(this);
    $.confirm({
        text: "Are you sure you want to delete that comment?",
        confirm: function() {
            // If you used $(this) here you referenced to your $(confirm) object

            // Instead of a false $(this), use the button that actually triggered this code.
            currentButton.trigger('click');
        }
    });
});
```

I am not sure if this is what you wanted to do, but please consider the code above is kind of an infinite loop, because when the click is triggered, this whole code will be called again.
Therefore if you wanted to press a different button, use the full selector of it, or assign him an unique ID and select it, as bellow:

*HTML code of targeted button:*

```
<input type="button" value="Button To Be Clicked after Confirm" name="myButton" id="uniqueID_onWholePage" />
```

*Updated jQuery code that presses on this button*

```
$(".btn-danger").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.confirm({
        text: "Are you sure you want to delete that comment?",
        confirm: function() {
            $('#uniqueID_onWholePage').trigger('click');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example that uses [SweetAlert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/), which is a replacement for Javascript built-in alert popup. If you have not checked out SweetAlert before, I highly recommend you do. [It also integrates very well with Bootstrap](https://lipis.github.io/bootstrap-sweetalert/).

Here is a working example (you may want to go full-screen for the full effect). Unfortunately, you will not be able to see the actual submit working, but the code should work once you add a real action.

```js
$("form.confirm").find("[type=submit]").click(function(e) {
  var $this;
  e.preventDefault();
  $this = $(this);
  return sweetAlert({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
    confirmButtonText: "Confirm Delete",
    closeOnConfirm: false
  }, function() {
    return $this.closest("form").submit();
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="confirm" method="POST" action"">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>  
</form>
```